How to obtain the mean value when the value occurs at least triplicate in the data? (Python)
I have a dataframe where based on the occurence of a value in column 'hit_num', I need to get the mean value of the column 'scores'. Below is an example of random data I created for this question:
# set random seed for reproducibility
np.random.seed(42)

# crate random pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'hit_num': np.random.randint(1,5,20), 
                   'score': np.random.randint(1, 500, 20),
                   })   
df.sort_values(by='hit_num')

Thus, if a value occurs at least three times in the hit_num column. I need to create a new dataframe where with the hit_num value and the average of the scores.
examlpe of the data I generated to create an idea
Thus hit_num 1 should be skipped, hit_num 2 should get mean of the 4 scores and hit_num 3 should get the mean of 7 scores.
I tried to work with np.mean() or with pandas mean, but I realized that it would just give the mean of the whole column. Next, I searched for column/row specific. I found something here on stackoverflow that showed how to get the mean of specific column/row combinations:
df[['b', 'c']].iloc[[2,4]].mean(axis=0)

but this was for a pre-set rowcolumn combination and I need it randomly to work.
I therefore thought I need something like a loop to first state hit_num > 3 and next the mean()?
However I got stuck here (I still am not sure if I should even do it like this):
for hits in df:
        if df['hit_num'].value_counts() < 3:
            continue
        elif df['hit_num'].value_counts() => 3:
            df.mean()

But I cannot figure out how to say take the mean of the 'score' columns, but only those with hit_num 2 for example.

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Set random seed for reproducibility
np.random.seed(42)

# Create random pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'hit_num': np.random.randint(1, 5, 20), 
                   'score': np.random.randint(1, 500, 20)})

# Group by 'hit_num', filter for those occurring at least 3 times, and calculate mean of 'score'
result = df.groupby('hit_num').filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 3).groupby('hit_num')['score'].mean().reset_index()

print(result)



Thank you so much! this works :) For future uses, is it possible to also do this in a situation where I want the mean of two columns (output two mean values one for scores andone for the 2nd column?
